# swapping container with self referencing element

Tags: c++

When a container contains elements which has a pointer to the container itself, the standard version of swap through pointer exchange doesn't work, and the swap doesn't check any such possibility. 
Is there any way to tell the container that standard swap doesn't work, and to use some different version? 
What is the best way to implement such swap?

The following example explains the problem.

```
template<template<typename T,typename = std::allocator<T> > class H>
struct kid
{
    typedef H<kid> home_type;
    typedef int id_t;
    kid(const home_type& home,int m,typename home_type::size_type c=-1)
        : home_(&home)
        , me_(m)
        , idx_(c)
    {

    }
    id_t me()const
    {
        return me_;
    }
    id_t cousin()const
    {
        return (*home_).size() < idx_ ? -1 : (*home_)[idx_].me();
    }
private://default copy & assign ok???
    const home_type* home_;
    typename home_type::size_type idx_;
    id_t me_;
};

int main()
{
    typedef kid<std::vector> kid_t;
    typedef std::vector<kid_t> home_t;
    home_t home1,home2;//two neighbors
    home1.push_back(kid_t(home1,1));//elderly kid
    home1.push_back(kid_t(home1,2,0));//the cousins
    home1.push_back(kid_t(home1,3,0));
    home1.push_back(kid_t(home1,4,0));

    home2.push_back(kid_t(home2,10));//first kid
    home2.push_back(kid_t(home2,20));//second kid
    home2.push_back(kid_t(home2,30,0));//cousin of first kid.
    home2.push_back(kid_t(home2,40,1));//cousin of second kid

    for(home_t::const_iterator it = home1.begin(); it!= home1.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout<<(*it).me()<<" "<<(*it).cousin()<<"\n";
    }
    std::cout<<"\n";
    for(home_t::const_iterator it = home2.begin(); it!= home2.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout<<(*it).me()<<" "<<(*it).cousin()<<"\n";
    }
    std::cout<<"\nexchange home\n";
    std::swap(home1,home2);//they exchanged their house, surely this doesn't work. 
    //what is the best way to do this?
    for(home_t::const_iterator it = home1.begin(); it!= home1.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout<<(*it).me()<<" "<<(*it).cousin()<<"\n";
    }
    std::cout<<"\n";
    for(home_t::const_iterator it = home2.begin(); it!= home2.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout<<(*it).me()<<" "<<(*it).cousin()<<"\n";
    }
    //all the kids got  confused, they points to neighborhood kids as their cousins 
}
```

In actual implementation, i have a class X with two vectors v1 & v2, while elements of v1 points to portion of v2. Simply swapping v1 & v2 doesn't work, as v1 contains pointer to v2 which also need to be updated. I am looking for the best way to implement such swap, without violating any encapsulation.

UPDATE

while i strongly dislike a public set_home for kid, as that is not part of kid's api and violates encapsulation, i also realized std::vector is not good. A dedicated home class is needed. 
A pointer based solution can always be done, as every level of indirection gives additional maneuverability. But that merely changes the problem rather than solving it.

One thing should be noted is that kids are not freestanding objects, they need home, and that is encoded in signature of kid. 
I feel that, a nothrow swap just swaps the pointer is too optimistic view. The swap for container should know whether it can do that optimization. This kind of problem also happens when storing std::vector of std::tr1::function, where the functor itself stores the reference/iterator to the vector.

I have this solution which just gives selective access to *set_home* to the home class using friendship, and stored as value rather than pointer.

But i still don't like the solution very much as i feel that swap should be intelligent enough to check if it can do what it want to do, as it already has information about *value_type* (here kid instance) which it doesn't use at all.

Here is the updated code.

```
template<template<typename T,typename = std::allocator<T> > class H>
struct kid
{
  typedef H<kid> home_type;
  typedef int id_t;
  kid(const home_type& home,int m,typename home_type::size_type c=-1)
    : home_(&home)
    , me_(m)
    , idx_(c)
  {

  }
 id_t me()const
 {
    return me_;
 }
 id_t cousin()const
 {
    return (*home_).size() < idx_ ? -1 : (*home_)[idx_].me();
 }
 private:
friend home_type;
void relocate(home_type& home)
{//private, not part of api.only home_type can call it.
    home_ = &home;
}
private://default copy & assign ok???
  const home_type* home_;
  typename home_type::size_type idx_;
  id_t me_;
};

template<typename T,typename Alloc = std::allocator<T> >
class home
{
typedef std::vector<T> base_t;
base_t h_;
public:
typedef typename base_t::size_type size_type;
typedef typename base_t::iterator iterator;
typedef typename base_t::const_iterator const_iterator;
void push_back(const T& t)
{
    h_.push_back(t);
}
size_type size()const
{
    return h_.size();
}
const T& operator[](size_type i)const
{
    return h_[i];
}
iterator begin()
{
    return h_.begin();
}
iterator end()
{
    return h_.end();
}
void swap(home<T,Alloc>& other)//nothrow swap if allocators are equal, though O(N).
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(h_,other.h_);
    for(iterator i = begin(), e = end();i!+ e; ++i)
    {
        (*i).relocate(h_);
    }
    for(iterator i = other.begin(), e = other.end();i!+ e; ++i)
    {
        (*i).relocate(other.h_);
    }
}
};

int main()
{
  typedef kid<home> kid_t;
  typedef home<kid_t> home_t;
  home_t home1,home2;//two neighbors
  home1.push_back(kid_t(home1,1));//elderly kid
  home1.push_back(kid_t(home1,2,0));//the cousins
  home1.push_back(kid_t(home1,3,0));
  home1.push_back(kid_t(home1,4,0));

  home2.push_back(kid_t(home2,10));//first kid
  home2.push_back(kid_t(home2,20));//second kid
  home2.push_back(kid_t(home2,30,0));//cousin of first kid.
  home2.push_back(kid_t(home2,40,1));//cousin of second kid

  for(home_t::const_iterator it = home1.begin(); it!= home1.end(); ++it)
  {
    std::cout<<(*it).me()<<" "<<(*it).cousin()<<"\n";
  }
  std::cout<<"\n";
  for(home_t::const_iterator it = home2.begin(); it!= home2.end(); ++it)
  {
    std::cout<<(*it).me()<<" "<<(*it).cousin()<<"\n";
  }
  std::cout<<"\nexchange home\n";
  using std::swap;
  swap(home1,home2);//they exchanged their house, surely this doesn't work. 
  //what is the best way to do this?
  for(home_t::const_iterator it = home1.begin(); it!= home1.end(); ++it)
  {
    std::cout<<(*it).me()<<" "<<(*it).cousin()<<"\n";
  }
  std::cout<<"\n";
  for(home_t::const_iterator it = home2.begin(); it!= home2.end(); ++it)
  {
    std::cout<<(*it).me()<<" "<<(*it).cousin()<<"\n";
  }
  //everything is fine here.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can implement std::swap for your type:

```
void std::swap(std::vector<kid_t> &first,std::vector<kid_t> &second)
{
  //here is your implementation or three lines of default swap
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any way of doing this using `swap`. The only way I can think of is providing a `move` function in `kid` which moves a kid from one home to the other. Then write your own function to move the kids around.

Comment: The main problem is move function have to be closely tied with swap of home in some way. So swap can't be independent of kid class. Also, just a move public member function causes problem, as if one kid moves and his/her cousin doesn't, it will be inconsistent state. 
i can implement the swap as 'three step dance' followed by one pointer (re) swap, but that will cost memory, and there won't be nothrow guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems more a problem of design than a problem of swap.

You (basically) use a pointer to a variable you did not assign yourself as an identifier of the kid... so of course as soon as the kids are moved around, it's going to break. (well it's slightly better than a pointer actually, but not by much)

You have 2 solutions:

- the basic > instantiate them yourselves
- the more complicated > factory + id

And of course you also have the problem that you tied up `Home` and its implementation... but I'll let you write a proper `Home` class by yourself. By the way, since the number of templates parameters of a STL container depend both on the container and on the actual implementation of the STL you are using, your solution is far less generic than using a real class ;)

**Basic**:

```
class kid
{
public:
  kid(kid* related = 0): m_related(related) {}
  // methods
private:
  // other attributes
  kid* m_related;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Home home1, home2;
  kid* kid1 = home1.insert(new kid(home1, 1));
  home1.insert(new kid(home1, 2, kid1));

  kid* kid2 = home2.insert(new kid(home2, 1));
  kid* kid3 = home2.insert(new kid(home2, 2));
  home.insert(new kid(home2, 3, kid2));
  home.insert(new kid(home2, 4, kid3));

  swap(home1,home2); // just swapping the vectors, since it only moves pointers not the objects
}
```

That's the easy way, but of course I still curse you because I have 2 kids with an id of 1...

**Factory**

```
 class KidFactory;

 class KidKey { friend class KidFactory; KidKey() {} };

 class Kid
 {
 public:
   Kid(KidKey, Id id, Id cousinId);

   Id getId() const { return m_id; }

   const Home* getHome() const;
   void setHome(const Home& home);

 private:
   const Home* m_home;
   Id m_id;
   Id m_cousinId;
 };

 // Factory
 class KidFactory
 {
 public:
   Kid& createKid(Id cousinId = -1)
   {
     m_kids.push_back(Kid(KidKey(), m_kids.size(), cousinId));
     return m_kids.back();
   }

   Kid& getKid(Id id)
   {
     return m_kids.at(id); // notice that might generate out_of_range exception
   }

 private:
   std::vector<Kid> m_kids;
 };

 class Home
 {
 public:
   void insert(Kid& kid)
   {
     m_kids.push_back(kid.getId());
     kid.setHome(*this);
   }
 };


 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
   KidFactory factory;
   Home home1, home2;

   home1.insert(factory.createKid());
   home1.insert(factory.createKid(home1.front().getId()));

   Kid& kid1 = factory.createKid();
   home2.insert(kid1);
   home2.insert(factory.createKid(kid1.getId()));

   // once again swapping vectors is fine
 }
```

Proper design leads to easy to write code... but some boilerplate one in C++ :(

Comment: I am not sure whether this is proper design. The first method doesn't solve the problem specified, it creates kid using new. and with arbitrary set of stable pointers one can always put a pointer to cousin.
For the second one, it just violets encapsulation. kid should not give his home address to public, someone could kidnap them. general public are also not allowed to set home for a kid. What will happen if some bad guy comes and set his home to a different locality, but not for his cousin. All the kids will get confused and point out to wrong cousin, just as it happens in my code.

Comment: rightly said by abir, getHome and setHome must be private if they are ever needed really.

Comment: I demonstrate a principle, you criticize a detail... Without knowing about your application, how can I say who is responsible for setting the Home of a new Kid ? It's your job to decide this, not mine, I never intended to do your job for you.

Comment: Not criticism, but the problem is that it changed the api to solve the problem. Secondly whenever factory resizes due to createKid, the kid pointer in home becomes invalid. Exactly for that reason in the original question i specifically said that the solution should not violet encapsulation. Your first solution is fine to me, though it changes requirement, as kid have to be created using new though it is not polymorphic. 
Still i don't see what is problem with the design, rather feel that swap for containers are over optimistic and swaps the private pointers without looking at value_type.

Comment: Sorry for being harsh, took me time to write the response and you just deride me on a peculiar point. I've edited the response too, the point of the factory was not to rely on pointers, but on ids (which also eases serialization). I don't see how this violate encapsulation that a `Kid` could change of `Home`, since your very question was about it :/ I understand your complaint about `std::vector` but C++ is about efficiency and this is efficient, if it does not suit you, you are free after all to write another version of `swap` for your own needs. Or you can stop relying on addresses ;)

Answer (score 0):

I agree that problem is in the design, but I think it's actually fairly simple to state: you're using object addresses as a form of object identity. This is a perfectly fine thing to do (it's precisely why C++ forbids 0-size objects - so each fully derived object has its own distinct address, and hence distinct identity), but if you do so, you should not treat your objects as value types, and randomly copy them around - or let any other class, such as `std::vector`, do so.

So, when it comes to semantics, when you swap two vectors that you have in your code, you aren't effectively swapping kids: you're *killing* kids in each house, and creating clones of them in the opposite house. Which is probably not quite the intended business logic.

I agree with Matthieu here that, if you use object addresses as object identity like that, then you need to allocate the kids yourself, and store pointers to them in your `vector`. If homes truly own kids, then use either `vector<shared_ptr<kid_t>>` or `boost::ptr_vector`. If homes do not own kids, and a kid can live without a home without being mercy-killed, then have a singleton `list<kid_t>` that owns and allocates all kids (and, being a `list`, will never reallocate implicitly), and then use `vector<kid_t*>` with pointers to objects in that `list` for every home.